# ExtJS Callback Functions Example

Tags: extjs4

I'm a newbie at ExtJs and I'm struggling to figure out how to use callback functions in ExtJs. The ExtJs version I'm using is 4.2.1
Basically I want to chain the execution of 2 functions:

func1: function() {
}

func2: function() {
}

so that func2() only starts executing after func1() completes.

From what I've read so far, I need to use callback function, but for the life of me I cannot get it.

Here Is my code:

```
filter: function (filters, value) {

    if (Ext.isString(filters)) {
        filters = {
            property: filters,
            value: value
        };
    }

    var me = this,
        decoded = me.decodeFilters(filters),
        i = 0,
        length = decoded.length;

    for (; i < length; i++) {
        me.filters.replace(decoded[i]);
    }

    Ext.Array.each(me.filters.items, function (filter) {
        Ext.Object.each(me.tree.nodeHash, function (key, node) {
            if (filter.filterFn) {
                if (!filter.filterFn(node)) node.remove();
            } else {
                if (node.data[filter.property] != filter.value) node.remove();
            }
        });
    });
    me.hasFilter = true;

    console.log(me);
},

clearFilter: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.filters.clear();
    me.hasFilter = false;
    me.load();
},

isFiltered: function() {
    return this.hasFilter;
},


filterNavAdminSTByUserName: function (nameValue) {

    this.clearFilter();

    this.filter([{
        property: 'userName',
        value: nameValue
    }]);

}
```

My problem is that this.filter() gets executed before this.clearFilter(); How do I force this.filter() to execute only after this.clearFilter() completes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Is `func1` an asynchronous method?

Comment: You can't set a method to be asynchronous. I'm asking does `func1` do anything that is asynchronous? Typically, an ajax request.

Comment: I didn't know you can set a method to be asynchronous in ExtJs 4.2.1. From what I know (limited knowledge as you can guess) all methods are async by default. How can I set that? Both func1 & func2 need to be sync? Or just func1?

Answer (score 0):

After some soul searching I've finally figured out how callback functions work.
So here is the solution:

```
clearAndFilter: function (nameValue) {
    var me = this;
    me.filters.clear();
    me.hasFilter = false;
    me.load({
        scope: me,
        callback: function () {
            // filter the store 
            me.filter('userName', nameValue);
        }

    });
},

filterNavAdminSTByUserName: function (nameValue) {
    this.clearAndFilter(nameValue);
}
```

Feels good to answer to my first ever post here!